# Get value from object with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript variable (selectCategory) that contains an object. When I console log the object I get the below output:

```
0: <input id="radio-2087915-2" class="input_category" type="radio" name="2087915" value="Food" checked="checked">
​
context: <input id="radio-2087915-2" class="input_category" type="radio" name="2087915" value="Food" checked="checked">
​
length: 1
```

I'm trying to get the name value from the object but whatever I try, for example: var name = selectCategory.name; results in a null value.

This is probably super basic but how can I get this value into a variable?

Comment: It looks like your object has a property called `"0"` (which is a valid property name) and that that property refers to a DOM element. So: `var name = selectCategory[0].name`. (Actually, it looks like a jQuery object. If it is, the previous example would work, but you could also do `var name = selectCategory.attr("name")`, which would be more idiomatic using jQuery.)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks var name = selectCategory.attr("name") did the trick, have learnt something new today!!